# How can the OS X Photos library be modified programatically?

Tags: macos, photos, photolibrary

The [Media Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MediaLibrary/Reference/MediaLibraryFrameworkReference/) appears to be read only and I can't see any methods that would allow modification of the library. Is there an API or mechanism that I have missed?

The specific changes that I want to make are the creation of albums based on external data.

The only mechanism that I can see for this is to directly modify the sqlite files comprising the database for the library but obviously this is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Applescript probably provides what I need although there may still be gaps.

Comment: Better more detailed answers or links to good resources welcomed and will be accepted if good.